# Pgadmin 4 row security issue

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm using pgadmin 4 web to administrate postgresql 9.3 server, so while restoring a database, i run into this error

```
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "row_security"
    La commande �tait : SET row_security = off;
```

But i noticed that my data is restored (dont know if 100% can't check it all)

And i can't grant any privilege to any user !!

My question is : can i ignore the error if it does restore all my data ? and how i can grant privilege to users using `Grant wizard` !

Comment: It looks like row security is a 9.5 feature that pg_restore tries to turn off by default. If your db doesn't require row security you should be fine.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring thanks for you replay, can you tell me how to know if a database require row security, cauz i'm lost i can't grant any privilege to any user and i think this is the problem !

Comment: Row security is on a per-table basis not the db as a whole. See the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for details. When you restored the db were the related roles created? [Note](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrole.html) that they're in a different (db-wide) table.

Answer (score 1):

The version of `pg_dump` used to create the database dump is higher than the version (9.3) you are using on the database server.

You should always use the same version of `pg_dump` as the database server into which you want to restore the dump (*not* the one from which you export the data).

You might get away with using `pg_restore` without the `-d` option to create an SQL script from the backup file. Then edit the SQL script, remove the offending line, and try to run the result against your 9.3 database. No success guaranteed!